# is there a way to sort GPS data by vehicle ID in R so that I can extract the starting point for all the vehicles

Tags: r, gps, spatial

I have passive GPS data(approx 500000 spatial points) for around 10,000 vehicles.I need to find the first point for each of the vehicles.Each spatial point is associated with its own id.I need to get the first point from each id.

Comment: Please provide some example data but yes that should be very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `data.frame` is called data1 and columns are vehicleID, x, y, etc.

```
data1[order(data1$vehicleID),]
```

If you want to just return the first point of each vehicle.

```
data1[data1$vehicleID==1,]
```